# How to deal with Http Promise AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Im trying to get the data from a response on http promise and set this data on attr from custome diretive, but always get a undefined data on my directive

```
promiseComboBox.then((response) =>
    {
        $scope.comboBoxTipoParking = response; //get data
    });

module.directive('comboBox', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
    return {
        restrict    : 'E',
        scope       : {
            data  : '=',
            label : '='
        },
        templateUrl : '/Scripts/components/select/select.html',
        link        : function(scope, element, attrs)
        {            
            console.log(attrs);//get here but undefined
            scope.label = attrs.label;


            $('.select2').select2({
                width           : '100%',
                dropdownParent  : $('.modalFocusInput')
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

```html
<combo-box label="Parqueadero" data="{{comboBoxTipoParking}}">
</combo-box>
```

//passing the result from http request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use [attrs.$observe](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes#$observe)

```
app.directive('comboBox', function(){
    return {
        restrict    : 'E',
        scope       : false,
        templateUrl : '/Scripts/components/select/select.html',
        link        : function(scope, element, attrs)
        {            
            console.log(attrs);//get here but undefined
            attrs.$observe("boxData", function(value) {
                console.log(value);
            });
        }     
    }
});
```

```
<combo-box label="Parqueadero" box-data="{{comboBoxTipoParking}}">
</combo-box>
```

Be careful when using the identifier `data` as an attribute. Directive [normalization](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization) strips the `data-` prefix.